# Zuul timing out in long-ish requests

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am using a front end Spring Cloud application (micro service) acting as a Zuul proxy ([`@EnableZuulProxy`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.4.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/EnableZuulProxy.html)) to route requests from an external source to other internal micro services written using spring cloud (spring boot).
The Zuul server is straight out of the applications in the samples section

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ZuulServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulServerApplication.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
}
```

I ran this set of services locally and it all seems to work fine but if I run it on a network with some load, or through a VPN, then I start to see Zuul forwarding errors, which I am seeing as client timeouts in the logs.

Is there any way to change the timeout on the Zuul forwards so that I can eliminate this issue from my immediate concerns?  What accessible parameter settings are there for this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The properties to set are: `ribbon.ReadTimeout` in general and `<service>.ribbon.ReadTimeout` for a specific service, in milliseconds.  The [Ribbon wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Programmers-Guide) has some examples.  [This javadoc](http://netflix.github.io/ribbon/ribbon-core-javadoc/com/netflix/client/config/CommonClientConfigKey.html) has the property names.

Comment: Thanks that helps.  Where would I find the default settings for all these parameters?

Comment: These are the configs: com.netflix.client.config.DefaultClientConfigImpl?

Comment: is it possible to set this property not only for ribbon if I'm not using it?

Answer (score 41):

In my case I had to change the following property:

```
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=30000
```

Comment: this is the solution when not using ribbon

Comment: is it possible to appy this solution per host to avoid applying it for all endpoints?

Comment: Can you please explain what this does? Is it a setting to increase the timeout between user logins, or to kill the page after 30 seconds?

Answer (score 23):

I have experienced the same problem: in long requests, Zuul's hystrix command kept timing out after around a second in spite of setting `ribbon.ReadTimeout=10000`.

I solved it by disabling timeouts completely:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
```

An alternative that also works is change Zuul's Hystrix isolation strategy to THREAD:

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: THREAD
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
```

Comment: thank you very very very much:-) The last one worked for me! Has it some disadvantages? Oh my god.. no timeouts anymore.. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think there's a problem. Actually, we've used in in production without problems so far. You can read more about why SEMAPHORE is the default implementation here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965817/why-is-zuul-forcing-a-semaphore-isolation-to-execute-its-hystrix-commands

Comment: To use this isolated to a specific service: # Disable Hystrix timeout for a single service:  
  
`hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.timeout.enabled: false`
  
# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (per service)  
`hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000`

Answer (score 22):

This worked for me, I had to set connection and socket timeout in the `application.yml`:

```
zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 60000 # starting the connection 
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000  # monitor the continuous incoming data flow
```

Comment: This worked for me. Short and simple. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 17):

I had to alter two timeouts to force zuul to stop timing out long-running requests. Even if hystrix timeouts are disabled ribbon will still timeout.

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        timeout:
          enabled: false
ribbon:
  ReadTimeout: 100000
  ConnectTimeout: 100000
```

Comment: thanks for this, last time I logged in to stackoverflow was in 2016, I had to login to say thank you and upvote

Answer (score 8):

If Zuul uses service discovery, you need to configure these timeouts with the `ribbon.ReadTimeout` and `ribbon.SocketTimeout` Ribbon properties.

If you have configured Zuul routes by specifying URLs, you need to use `zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis` and `zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis`

by routes i mean

```
zuul:
  routes:
    dummy-service:
      path: /dummy/**
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I was trying to set **timeout** globally, and also sequence of setting timeout for **Hystrix** and **Ribbon** matters.

After spending plenty of time, I ended up with this solution. My service was taking upto 50 seconds because of huge volume of data.

Points to consider before changing default value for Timeout:

**Hystrix** time should be greater than combined time of **Ribbon** ReadTimeout and ConnectionTimeout.

**Use** for specific service only, which means don't set globally (which doesn't work).

I mean use this:

```
command:
   your-service-name:
```

instead of this:

```
command:
   default:
```

Working solution:

```
hystrix:
 command:
   your-service-name:
  execution:
    isolation:
      strategy: THREAD
      thread:
        timeoutInMilliseconds: 95000

your-service-name:
 ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 30000
  ReadTimeout: 60000
  MaxTotalHttpConnections: 500
  MaxConnectionsPerHost: 100
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280765/6332074)

Comment: What about timeout for specific route of service ?

Answer (score 1):

Only these settings on `application.yml` worked for me:

```
ribbon:
    ReadTimeout: 90000
    ConnectTimeout: 90000

eureka:
    enabled: true

zuul:
    host:
        max-total-connections: 1000
        max-per-route-connections: 100
    semaphore:
        max-semaphores: 500

hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
                isolation:
                    thread:
                        timeoutInMilliseconds: 1000000
```

Hope it helps someone!